# In Excel VBA, how do I deactivate a cell if the user enters a file name without specifying a file format?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working in Excel VBA, and the "Details" and "status" columns are both present.

When the column Status for "Completed" is Y, the Column "File Name" should be updated with the file format abc.doc/abc.pdf/abc.jpeg. If the user merely updates the file name, the cell should not enable the user to do so.

How it should be done in Excel VBA?

**Excel Data**

```
Details                Status
Completed(Y/N)        Y or N in Dropdown
File Name             abc.doc/ abc.pdf/abc.jpg
```

**Code**

```
   ' If Completed is Y, then File name should be available with file extension (File format - .docx/.xlsx/.pdf/jpeg)
    If Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = "Y" Then
        If Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value = "" Or Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value = "" Then
        
        MsgBox "Error: If 'Completed' is filled with Y then the file name must be filled with its file format .docx/.xlsx/.pdf/jpeg"
        End If
    
    ElseIf Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = "N" Then
        If Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Error : If 'Completed' is N then 'File Name' must be blank"
        Range("B3").Value = ""
        End If
    End If
    
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish! If you just want to avoid the user from selecting cell B3 (filename) then **Worksheet_SelectionChange** event might be enough.

Put this code in **Sheet1 module**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' if the user tries to select B3 then cell B2 will be selected
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3")) Is Nothing Then Target.Offset(-1, 0).Select
End Sub
```